# Regular expression not working in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have regular expression in Angular2 code where i am trying to validate if form contains string or integer, but it does not work properly. If i write numbers into form it should say "success", but it does not.

**app.component.ts**

```
formText: string = "";

formValidate(cardNumber1: string):void{
 var re = /^[0-9]+$/;

 if(!re.test(("cardNumber1"))){   
     this.formText = "Please enter numbers only"; //even if i enter numbers, it still says "Please enter numbers only".
 }else{
     this.formText = "Success"; 
 }

 }
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <input type="text" #cardNumber1 name="card-number1" class="card-form" 
   id="card-number1" cardNumber1.value="">

  <div class="form-text">{{formText}}</div>
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your HTML.

Comment: Not enough info. How are you getting the string from the input in the TS file?

Comment: I have a button in app.component.html                                               
    <input type="button" value="pay" class="pay-btn" id="credit-card-pay" (click)='formValidate(cardNumber1.value)'>

Comment: add your `button` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

**app.component.ts**

```
formText: string = "";

formValidate(cardNumberValue: string):void{


    var re = /^[0-9]+$/;

     if(!re.test(cardNumberValue)){   
         this.formText = "Please enter numbers only";
     }else{
         this.formText = "Success"; 
     }

 }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="button" value="pay" class="pay-btn" id="credit-card-pay" (click)="formValidate(cardNumber1.value)">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could instead use the built-in pattern validator. Something like this:

```
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="emailId" 
                           type="email" 
                           placeholder="Email (required)" 
                           required
                           pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+"
                           [(ngModel)]="customer.email"
                           name="email"
                           #emailVar="ngModel" />
                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(emailVar.touched || emailVar.dirty) && emailVar.errors">
                        <span *ngIf="emailVar.errors.required">
                            Please enter your email address.
                        </span>
                        <span *ngIf="emailVar.errors.pattern">
                            Please enter a valid email address.
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

NOTE: Email is now a bad example because Angular supports the type="email" validation. But it demonstrates the mechanics of using the pattern validator.